Bitbucket SSH instructions for Git for Windows says to use .bashrc
From page https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-personal-ssh-keys-on-windows/, section "Start the SSH agent", sub-section "Git for Windows users (including Winget-based Git installations)", it says to use Git Bash to run ps -a | grep ssh-agent, then if ssh-agent isn't already running, to start the agent using eval $(ssh-agent) (running the ps statement again doesn't show any evidence of the agent running, but that's a different issue).
It then says:

You may need to add this command to your ~/.bashrc to ensure the agent starts when you open a Git Bash terminal.

However, there's no ~/.bashrc. I'm using Windows 11 Pro.
Am I supposed to create the file .bashrc in my home folder C:\Users\Me? Does Git Bash create it automatically through some trigger that Atlassian has expected to already have been done with my Git for Windows install? I'm confused on what they mean here.
Anyway, I'm used to .bashrc in Linux, not Windows.
